# multiplying Python Dataframe column with a fixed variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I could perform subtracting a Dataframe column with a constant. Example:

```
snp_sum = snp['Adj Close'] - 10
```

However, it doesn't work once I replace the constant with a variable `snp_30Y`:

```
snp_30Y = ((snp_t1-snp_t0)/snp_t0)
snp_30Y = snp_30Y.values 
snp_sum = snp['Adj Close'] - snp_30Y
```

Results I get is `ValueError: Length of passed values is 1, index implies 360`

Results should be the same as if I defined the variable as a constant number like 10.

```
snp_sum = snp['Adj Close'] - 10
```

results:

```
0       267.720001
1       287.470001
2       278.859985
3       284.869995
4       299.640015
```

Comment: How about `snp_sum = snp['Adj Close'] - snp_30Y[0]`?

Comment: What are `snp_t1` and `snp_t0`? You need to [edit] the question to clarify. Read [mre] for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As [wjandrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518341/wjandrea) pointed out, your example is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, the title does not match the example: you mention multiplying while the example shows some subtraction.

So here is some general answer, but please update your question if you wish to get a more specific one.

You **can** operate on two dataframe columns (multiplying, subtracting, etc.) but only if they have the same dimension. You can check that dimension using `<col>.shape` or `len(<col>)`.

Note also that in pandas there are several types you should know about: a full dataframe is a `Dataframe` while a single column is a `Series`. These objects are wrappers of more low-level and efficient `numpy` objects named `array`. You can access these lower-level objects by using `<col_or_df>.values`. Operations between `Series` and `Series` are supported, as well as between `Series` and `array`. THat's why you have two ways to perform what you ask for:

```
import pandas as pd

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 10, 20],
                   'b': [1, 11, 21]})

# subtracting a constant
df_cst = df['a'] - 1
print("df_cst (type subtracted: %s)" % type(1))
print(df_cst)
print()

# subtracting a column (= a Series)
df_var = df['a'] - df['b']
print("df_var (type subtracted: %s)" % type(df['b']))
print(df_var)
print()

# subtracting a column values (= a numpy array)
df_var2 = df['a'] - df['b'].values
print("df_var2 (type subtracted: %s)" % type(df['b'].values))
print(df_var2)
```

Yields

```
df_cst (type subtracted: <class 'int'>)
0    -1
1     9
2    19
Name: a, dtype: int64

df_var (type subtracted: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>)
0   -1
1   -1
2   -1
dtype: int64

df_var2 (type subtracted: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>)
0   -1
1   -1
2   -1
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

As you can see, when only one of the two variables in the subtraction is a dataframe column (a `Series`), then the result carries its name over. When the second item is also a `Series`, the name is lost since pandas has no way to know which name to use for the result.